# Start GET request with a HTML button

Tags: html

I have these two lines of code:

```
<form method="link" action="insert.php">
<input id="nav" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

and

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_user( {$id} );'>Delete</a>";
```

What I'd like to do is that I can echo a button that deletes a raw in the database.
The link does it right now but it looks really bad. I thought if it's possible to replace the same action with a button.
Is it possible?

Is it something along the lines:

```
echo "<input id='nav' value='Delete' type='submit' onclick='delete_user( {$id} )';
```

Probably not, because that doesn't work :D

Comment: Just add some CSS to the link so it looks like a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out:

```
<button onclick='delete_user( {$id} )'>Delete</button>
```

Comment: why not to wrap $id inside php tag..? +1 for you to answer same before me..just use <?php echo $id; ?> inside onClick

Answer (score 1):

Change : `type='submit'` to `type='button'` and try